# Point subtraction in elliptic curve cryptography

Tags: c, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I want to do point subtraction on an elliptic curve on a prime field. I tried taking the points to be subtracted as `(x,-y log(p))` but my answer doesn't seem to match.

This is how I tried to do the subtraction:

```
 s9=point_addition(s6.a,s6.b,((s8.a)%211) ,-((s8.b)%211));
```

here `s9`, `s6` and `s8` are all structures with two `int`.

and this is my function which does the point addition:

```
structure point_addition(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    int s,xL,yL;
    if((x1-x2)!=0)
    {
        if ((((y1-y2)/(x1-x2)) % 211)>0)
              s=(((y1-y2)/(x1-x2)) % 211);
        else
              s=(((y1-y2)/(x1-x2)) % 211) + 211;
        if ((((s*s)-(x1+x2)) % 211)>0)
              xL= (((s*s)-(x1+x2)) % 211) ;
        else
              xL= (((s*s)-(x1+x2)) % 211) + 211;
        if(((-y1+s*(x1-x2)) % 211)>0)
              yL= ((-y1+s*(x1-xL)) % 211);
        else
              yL= ((-y1+s*(x1-x2)) % 211) + 211;
    }
    else
    {
        xL= 198 ;
        yL= 139;
    }

    s7.a= xL;
    s7.b= yL;

    return s7 ;
}
```

The programs doesn't seem to give me the correct co-ordinates Please help me with this coding for elliptic curve cryptography.

Comment: Don't forget to tag the language you are performing the calculation in Jowin, if only to increase the number of views. I've guessed C, but you can re-edit your question to change that.

Comment: Jowin, "division" mod p means you have to compute a [modular inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_inverse). `s=(((y1-y2)/(x1-x2)) % 211)` is not the correct way to do it.

Comment: GregS, I see I have to edit my code to do division with modular inverse method.. but I wonder how even with normal division Whatever points I got were on the elliptic curve!.. Thanks a lot for your answer! and In my program an infinity point has to be considered for the ellipse what point can I take for that?

Answer (score 2):

See GregS's comment about division mod p. You need to find the inverse of the denominator and then multiply. To calculate the modular inverse you could use the extended euclidean algorithm.

Also the way you're negating the y coordinate then adding 211 later is a bit odd. Best to keep field elements in the proper range when passing as arguments, e.g. to obtain -y mod p, use p-y.

And I assume this is just a learning exercise since you're using a very small field :)

Comment: Could you please elaborate I feel that p-y is what I am finding to replace -y mod(p) in my program Correct me if I am wrong on this.

Comment: Yes I think it's ok in your case. I'm just saying that using different representations of the same field element is asking for trouble. Say you passed x1=210 and x2=-1 to point_addition.The check if((x1-x2)!=0) would not work.

Answer (score 1):

I don`t understand what you are doing there exactly, what your log(p) is supposed to mean and where your domain parameters enter, but subtracting is easy:
Negate the y-coordinate (-Y = modulus - y) and then plainly add as usual.

If you want a reference for your calculations, you might use my open source software "Academic Signature"
from [this link](http://www.fh-wedel.de/~an/crypto/accessories/easy_download_eng.html)
It is quite transparent with its calculations and produces e.g. results of ECDSA-signatures in human readable hex notation. I am not sure at the moment though, if it can do calculations with such short moduli you are working with.

The manual featuring descriptions on how to program ECC-operations correctly and how to use the software is there:
[Link to ecc Manual](http://www.fh-wedel.de/~an/crypto/Academic_signature_eng.html)

Regards
  Michael Anders

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael. What I am trying to do is to implement the following tutuorial in c http://www.dkrypt.com/home/ecc The p is the p from the elliptic curve equation 
 { y2 mod p= x3 + ax + b mod p } and I downloaded your program it was impressive can the program be able to find this
1 Given elliptic curve equation y^2 mod(211) = (x^3 - 4) mod(p) The private key is 4 and generator points is (2, 2) Numbers 0- 200 are mapped on the curve  Numbers to be encrypted using method in tutorial and sent  4,5,6 are sent can it tell the encrypted points and the decypted points